# Is it possible to append one xtype to another in Ext JS

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

Is there any way to append two xtypes in single. I mean i have one xtype as textfield and other one as button.
Here i am giving the code for a button next to a textfield and its working.
But now i need both the textfield and button in single.

```
   {
        layout: "column",
        anchor: "0",
        items: [{
            columnWidth: .5,
            layout: "form",
            items: {
                xtype: "textfield",
                name: "agent",
                fieldLabel: "Representant",
                anchor: "0"
            }
        },{
            columnWidth: .5,
            items: {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Click me'
            }
        }]
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**xtype or widget**

A xtype is a sort of a shortconstructor for a class. What you can nest inside a class depends on the class. As for a textfield you can't append any childs. You should take a look at the [API](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/) if you want more info about any class. Basicly you can nest them as you did it in your question

**For what you want**

To makes this really clean you could either extend textfield, use triggerfield (this one has already buttons where you can change the layout) or write a plugin which then can get appended to any appropriate field.

**Comment Answer**

You can try the following untested code! Instead of a composite field you could also use a `container` with a applied `hbox` layout. But this feels more suitable for me.

```
{
    xtype: 'compositefield',
    labelWidth: 120
    items: [
        {
            xtype     : 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Title',
            flex      : 1,
            ref       : '../myTextfieldRef' // set a selfreference to the ownerCt
        },
        {
            xtype     : 'button',
            iconCls   : 'icon-class-name',
            text      : 'My Button Text',
            width     : 20,
            ref       : '../myButtonRef', // set a selfreference to the ownerCt
            handler   : function(btn) {
                console.log(btn.ownerCt.myTextfieldRef.value);
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you. triggerfield is ok, but its looking like combofield so that i cannot use it. So is it possible to customize a new xtype for both textfield and button from ext.form.textfield and ext.form.button?

Answer (score 1):

For your requirement, as being said by sra, it is better to use triggerfield (or twinTriggerField if you have two buttons).

For combining other fields, you can also take a look at [compositeField](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.form.CompositeField).